# Can not access variable from an instance of a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I have declared a variable of a class in the `def __init__()` but when I create an instance of that class and try to access one of the variables I created it says "object has no attribute"

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import Window
from Renderer import Renderer


class Window(Window):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.renderer = Renderer()
        self.test = 1
        glClearColor(255, 0, 0, 255)

window = pyglet.window.Window(400, 300, "Window", resizable=True)
print(window.test)
```

Renderer is a class I've made, but pyglet is a library

The problem here is that I can't access `window.renderer`, nor `window.test`.

Error: `AttributeError: 'Win32Window' object has no attribute 'test'`
How can I solve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind posting the entire traceback?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are making an instance of *your* window class. You are making an instance of `pyglet.window.Window`

Comment: @DanielWalker Thank you for the reply :)
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/user/Projects/Python/Project/Window.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(window.test)
AttributeError: 'Win32Window' object has no attribute 'test'

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you so much! I completely forgot to remove the ```pyglet.window``` :)

Comment: do **not** name classes the same as the classes you inherit, as this might cause issues further down the line. Especially if you want to create two windows. either do `Window(pyglet.window.Window)` and import pyglet with `import pyglet` instead of `from pyglet.window import Window`. Or rename your class to `MyWindow(Window)` instead. As you're replacing the imported `Window` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window = Window(400, 300, "Window", resizable=True)
```

would create an instance of your custom `Window`.